# In Symfony disabled field doesn't sent in request

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

In Symfony 1.4 
if i have form contain disabled fields 
when i submit the form the disabled fields doesn't send in form fields

Answer (score 2):

This is probably no symfony issue but rather a normal HTML behaviour:

> A disabled field is not even sent if the form is submitted.
>   http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html

Answer (score 0):

It's an HTML behaviour. If you don't want some fields to be displayed, just make them hidden

Answer (score 0):

no it is not actually "submitted", suggests use the object(a parameter of instantiating the form) to set its default value.